# What should I type, to create an object of the Function class?

Tags: python

I have a list of polynomial coefficients. I just don't know what to pass to the constructor. How should I create an object of the class Function?

Thank you!

```py
class Function():
    
    def __init__(self, coef):
        """print(coef, min(coef), max(coef))
        keys = range(min(coef), max(coef)+1)
        self.__coef= {}
        for key in keys:
            self.__coef[key] = complex(coef[key]) if key in coef else complex(0)"""
        self.__coef = {key: complex(value) for key, value in coef.items() if value != 0}
        print(self.__coef)

    @property
    def coef(self):
        """
        Return a list object composed with all the polynomial's coeficients
        shifted to have them starting with first exponantiation as 0.
        Exponentiation for each is now the index in the list.
        """
        indexes = list(self.__coef.keys())
        index = min(indexes) if min(indexes) < 0 else 0
        coef = []
        remains = len(indexes)
        while remains > 0:
            if index in self.__coef:
                remains -= 1
            coef.append(self.__coef.setdefault(index, 0))
            index += 1
            
        return coefficients
```

Comment: it looks like `coefs` needs to be a dictionary. From the code is not clear what the keys should be. you can try something like `coefs = {2: 3, 1: 4, 0: 5}` to generate the polynomial   `3x^2 + 4x + 5`  where the key is the degree and the value is the coefficient value

Answer (score 0):

To create an object of any class simple do the following:

```
obj = ClassName()
```

In this case, to create an object of your class do the following:

```
obj = Function(coef)
```

Replace `coef` with the values you want to enter